# Displaying the elements of my LinkedList does not work

Tags: java, list, linked-list

After calling the remove method, I call display and I'm getting an empty list; however, if I call the display method first it will display the correct list, I'm guessing the "first" value reached the end of the list or I got a broken node somewhere. Any help appreciated

```
public class LinkedList {

    private Node first;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
    }

    //add students to the list
    public void add(Student s)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(s);
        newNode.next = first;
        first = newNode;        
    }

    //remove duplicate records (return true if duplicate found)
    public boolean remove(String fn, String ln)
    {
        Student remove;
        boolean found = false;
        int duplicate = 0;
        while(first != null)
        {
            if(first.value.getFname().equals(fn) && first.value.getLname().equals(ln))
            {
                duplicate++;
                if(duplicate > 1)
                {
                    remove = first.value;
                    found = true;  

                }                
            }
            first = first.next;
        }
        if(found)
            return found;
        else
            return found;
    }

    //display list of student
    public void display()
    {
        if(first == null)
            System.out.println("List is empty!");
        else
        {
            while(first != null)
            {
                System.out.println(first.value);
                first = first.next;
            }            
        }            
    }

}
```

main

```
public class Tester {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UnderGrad john = new UnderGrad("john", "doe", 2.7, "computer Science", "phisics");
        UnderGrad jorge = new UnderGrad("jorge", "vazquez", 3.8, "computer Science", "programming");
        UnderGrad john2 = new UnderGrad("john", "doe", 3.0, "Computer Engineering", "phisics");

        Advisor jim = new Advisor("jim", "smith");

        Grad jane = new Grad("jane", "doe", 3.0, "Electric Engineering", jim);       


        LinkedList students = new LinkedList();

        students.add(john);
        students.add(jorge);
        students.add(john2);
        students.add(jane);


        System.out.println(students.remove("john", "doe"));

        students.display();


    }
}
```

output

```
run:
true
List is empty!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: You are never removing anything...you just look if something is in the list and iterate to its end, where first = null. You can break out of the while loop by using the "break" statement. Also you are always returning "found" - so no need for the if-else at the end.

Comment: how do you know that first = null... I don't see it

Comment: I'm sure if breaking out of the loop is the right solution.. how about if there's more than one duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the linked list's head (`first`) as an iterator in the `remove` method. Instead, use a local variable:

```
for (Node current = first; current != null; current = current.next) {
    if (current.value.getFname().equals(...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: yeah, but if I use a local variable when I use my display method which use the "first" variable it prints the whole array. I have not removed anything...

Answer (score 1):

You have a few bugs.  You cannot possibly mean this:
        if(found) 
            return found; 
        else 
            return found;

That will always return true.

Set a breakpoint, draw a picture of the data structure (yes with a pencil) and watch the data structure in the debugger as you walk through the code.

If you get a code answer here, you will not be able to figure out the next assignment either.  Sorry.

-Professor Archibald.

Comment: The `if (found)...` thing will *not* always return true. It is exactly equivalent to a simple `return found`.

Answer (score 1):

Step through your code and pay attention to what happens to the value of `first` after the first call to `remove(...)`.

Hint: it will be `null`.

Since `LinkedList.first` is the only reference from `LinkedList` to its contents, after you call `remove()` the list has 'forgotten' what it contains.

Comment: well, I got two problem here, 1 I'm not removing anything, and 2 b/c I'm using a class variable when first = first.next reaches its end of course first = null therefore "dipalay" method is empty. One solution would be to use a local variable and iterate throug list but how can I remove a link?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your add( ) method. look in there. :)